# HighCharts - getJson to HighCharts dual axes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I would like to display a HighCharts dual axes chart by making a call to a local webService, which returns Json (example given below).

The HighChart should plot the following data points:

- y-axis left: plots the 'Movement'
- y-axis right: plots the 'EndValue'
- x-axis: plots the 'DateLabel'

My Json webservice call: http://localhost/api/getData?format=jsonp

This returns the following Json:

```
    {
  "LastUpdated": "/Date(-62135596800000-0000)/",
  "TotalTime": "0s584ms",
  "MonthlyData": {
    "GroupId": 9,
    "CurrencyId": 3,
    "Returns": [
      {
        "Movement": -0.008536959525287496,
        "MovementLabel": "-0.85 %",
        "DateLabel": "Jan-10",
        "Date": "/Date(1264892400000-0000)/",
        "EndValue": 16012000.007666545
      },
      {
        "Movement": -0.04846365302964577,
        "MovementLabel": "-4.85 %",
        "DateLabel": "Feb-10",
        "Date": "/Date(1267311600000-0000)/",
        "EndValue": 15235999.994984308
      },
      {
        "Value": -0.0034129684178402725,
        "ValueLabel": "-0.34 %",
        "DateLabel": "Mar-10",
        "Date": "/Date(1269986400000-0000)/",
        "StartValue": 15235999.994984308,
        "EndValue": 15184000.008187212,
        "CashFlows": 0


       }
    ]
  }
}
```

What is the jquery code needed to 
- make the call to the webService (I would like to use getJson)
- transform the JSON output to the required HighCharts data, such that a dual axes chart can be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get JSON you can use `jQuery.ajax()` function. As for the splitting data into two series linked to different yAxis, you need to parse your data. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.opposite

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dna9wqsg/

Comment: What an awesome answer. Love the fact that you recreated the JSON in json generator & full code in JsFiddle. AWESOME!

Comment: Thanks. I am glad it is helpful for you. Cheers!

Comment: do you know why the 0 value is not pushed into the graph? If I look at the highChart as per JSFiddle the zero values are not put into line graph?

Comment: How so? From what I see, 0 values are pushed into data without any problems. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ch31dm6z/.